# Make an iteration over an 2D array for indexing an 3D array more pythonic and skip zero values

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D Array of values, and a 3D array of corresponding values. The value of the number in the 2D array is the index for the first dimension in the 3D array, while the index of the value in the 2D array is the same as in the 3D array for the last two dimensions.

Furthermore, if the value in the 2D array is 0 no look up should be done, and the value should stay 0.

I wrote a simple script with two loops iterating over the rows, and then over the elements, which looks like the following:

```
c = np.array(np.random.rand(424,512)*10,dtype=np.int32)

mean_error_map = np.random.rand(42,424,512)

mean_map = np.zeros(shape=(c.shape[0],c.shape[1]))

for x,element_row in enumerate(c):

    if element_row.sum() == 0:
        continue

    for y,element in enumerate(element_row):

        if element == 0:
            continue

        mean_map[x,y] = mean_error_map[int(element),x,y]
```

I wonder if there is a more pythonic / numpy way to achieve the same behaviour which may result in a speed up.

Comment: Can you show a toy example of the data?

Comment: They are included in the snippet at the top